# Quantify the area of a shape in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes

In Inkscape, is there a way to automatically calculate the space / area a shape occupies? I am representing data in complex shapes and I need a way to scale them accordingly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To automatically obtain the area of a shape in pixel, cm and so on simply select the shape, go to `Extensions > Visualise Path > Measure Path ...` and select the desired output. It does not work for objects though (for example rectangles drawn with the `Create rectangles and squares` tool). Convert them to paths before (`Path > Object to Path`).

Comment: The indications are all good, but nothing happens either with Length, Area, or Center of Mass. I have Inkscape 0.91.

Comment: It works for me on Inkscape 0.92.3.  However, it does not appear to support anything other than regular paths.  For example, I was not able to get results for an entire group, but it worked for individual paths once I ungrouped them.

Comment: Just great. Thank a lot +1. I was calculating rooms surfaces in an office plane and that made the task a piece of cake.

Comment: Yes, Works like wonder in Inkscape 0.92 !  Had to install `python-lxml` and `python-numpy` as prerequisites for the area-finder to calculate... but that helped us four friends divide six plots of land in ratios of 21:21:37:69 like a magic wand !  Wish the Egyptians and Romans had something like this too !!!